# Text field extension with button in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

How do I crate a special Ext.form.TextField with a button. When the user clicks on it it will show a list of of items to choose from. When something is selected it will come back to the parent form populating the form with selected item.

Answer (score 6):

You have just perfectly described a ComboBox so you may want to look into using that instead:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox

If you still want a button next to a TextField, however, then you can use a CompositeField:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.CompositeField

```
var MyField = new Ext.form.TextField({
    name: 'my_field',
    flex: 1
});

new Ext.form.CompositeField({
    fieldLabel: 'My field',
    items: [
        MyField,
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Choose item'
            handler: function() {
                // Show a menu or selection dialog, then set the user's
                // selected value with:
                MyField.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Will it set the value to the parent component?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by the parent component. The value being set in the example code is on the TextField stored in MyField. It is only an example to illustrate placement of a button next to a field, however. Any action desired may be placed in the button's handler.

Comment: +1, for ExtJS 4 you will use instead a `FieldContainer` (see the doc here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer) since `CompositeField` no longer exists.